# Using STL to bind multiple function arguments

Tags: c++, stl

In the past I've used the bind1st and bind2nd functions in order to do straight forward operations on STL containers.  I now have a container of MyBase class pointers that are for simplicities sake the following:

```
class X
{
public:
    std::string getName() const;
};
```

I want to call the following static function using for_each and binding both the 1st and 2nd parameters as such:

StaticFuncClass::doSomething(ptr->getName(), funcReturningString() );

How would I use for_each and bind both parameters of this function?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
for_each(ctr.begin(), ctr.end(), 
         bind2Args(StaticFuncClass::doSomething(), 
                   mem_fun(&X::getName), 
                   funcReturningString());
```

I see Boost offers a bind function of its own that looks like something that would be of use here, but what is the STL solution?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Just to be clear, for each element `e` in the sequence, you want to call `StaticFuncClass::doSomething(e.getName(), funcReturningString())`?

Comment: yes...technically it would be e->getName() because the elements in the container are pointers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A reliable fallback when the bind-syntax gets too weird is to define your own functor:

```
struct callDoSomething {
  void operator()(const X* x){
    StaticFuncClass::doSomething(x->getName(), funcReturningString());
  }
};

for_each(ctr.begin(), ctr.end(), callDoSomething());
```

This is more or less what the `bind` functions do behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: +1  Yes, I had thought about that too.  I was just wondering if there was an inline way to do it like binding only 1 of the 2 using bind1st or bind2nd.

Comment: No need for a constructor, though.

Comment: It might be possible with the STL bind functions, but it gets a bit too hairy for me. I'd prefer the functor approach. Of course in C++0x you could define it inline with a lambda

Comment: @xtofl: doh, you're right. I'm not sure I want to edit it though. Seems to get CW'ed awfully fast when I do that. ;)

Comment: And you can make it even smaller by using a `void callDoSomething( const X* x )` function.  (PS: what's CW?)

Comment: community wiki. Happens if you edit your post too often. And I already made a few edits to this one. ;)

As for making it a function, true, but then it'd be harder for the compiler to inline.

Answer (score 4):

The "STL solution" would be to write your own binder... that's why they created the powerful boost::bind.

Answer (score 3):

You can either create a local functor structure, which can be inlined by the compiler (as Jalf showed), or use a simple function:

```
void myFunc( const X* x ) { 
    StaticFuncClass::doSomething(x->getName(), funcrReturningString() ); 
}

for_each( c.begin(), c.end(), myFunc );
```

Comment: the & shouldn't be necessary. Functions can be implicitly converted to function pointers, so just `myFunc` would work afaik.